# Imperative USQL

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

How do I write control code for USQL?  For example, move records between rowsets depending on the result of a query, and do this iteratively?  Do I need to write a C# wrapper that dynamically generates and submits USQL?

For example, imagine I am writing a type of divisive hierarchical clustering algorithm.  I have a large data set, where each row represents a point I want to segment.  I iteratively repeat the following procedure:

```
For next cluster of rows X on stack:
    For each potential disjoint subsegment Y of X:
        Test if Y is different than (X-Y)
        If yes:
            mark Y as cluster and push to stack
            let X=X-Y
```

Obviously, this procedure involves lots of control flow.  How could I implement such a routine in USQL?  If it is not possible, how would I implement with ADLA?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  Can you write some pseudo-code that better describes what you want to do and we'll see if it can be done in U-SQL.  Consider working through some of the tutorials or [U-SQL Programmability Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-programmability-guide) to get a good understanding of what the language can do.

Comment: @wBob thanks.  Added psuedocode as requested.  I've been through the programmability and tutorials guide a few times, but don't think they really address what I am asking.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks more suited to R or Python maybe.  Microsoft have just updated R Server to [v9.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/) which is worth a look.  Is there any particular reason you are trying to use U-SQL for this?

Comment: @wBob Thanks! It's my understanding I need to use USQL for ADLA.  Is that not correct? If not, kindly refer me to a resource for using Python or R with ADLA.

Comment: Yes you can use USQL, you can also use Python, Node.js, and Java.  Full details here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/